# XML Nested Attributes and XSD.exe

Tags: .net, xml, xsd.exe

I am running into an issue where I am trying to build a proxy class, but the XML schema has nested attributes.  Here is a forum post about the issue - [.NET Nested Attributes](http://www.opentravelcommunityforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19&p=179&hilit=Cannot+implicitly+convert+type+VendorMessageType%27+to+VendorMessageType%5b%5d#p179), but I am wondering if there is not an easier way to do this?  Any help is appreciated.

Wade

Comment: can you be more specific?  Rather than linking to something else that records a lengthy discussion between other people about i-don't-know-what, can you specifically describe what you are trying to do, and the problem you're encountering while trying to do it?  a small bit of sample code for illustration is  also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by this post on Stack Overflow - ['Error serializing body'. Problem calling Fedex webservice through .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345411/error-serializing-body-problem-calling-fedex-webservice-through-net-3-5).  Specifically, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326790/en-us.

Wade